# Is it creating many variables bad for performance in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose there's a scope where variables are created in a loop... e.g, loop that is always executed in a repetitive call of game frame.

```
for(var i = 0; i !== 10; i ++) {
    for(var b = 0; b !== 10; b ++);
}
```

And if the variable `i` and the variables `b` (created 10 times on each time the loop block executes) in this code aren't removed from memory? JavaScript garbage collector shouldn't work equally in browsers.

I need to know what happens to these temporary variables created many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` variables are function scoped. Their declaration will be moved to the top of the function, and will only happen once. This is called hoisting.

Then, your code will become something like

```
var i, b;
// ...
for(i = 0; i !== 10; i ++) {
    for(b = 0; b !== 10; b ++);
}
```

And of course, creating 2 variables is not problematic.

Comment: So if the original code used `let` instead of `var`, would *that* be bad for performance?

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't think it would be really bad, but when you use `let` or `const` in a loop, a new binding is created at each iteration. (Well, at least this is what should happen. Firefox didn't do it last time I checked). So if a browser didn't implement this in an optimized way, it could be a bit slower.

Comment: And these `i` and `b` will be created everytime a game frame loop function is being called? (Suppose these loops are declared into a game loop function.) I didn't know about that, though.

Comment: @CoolMan Yes, each time you call the function, new `i` and `b` variables will be created.

Comment: @Oriol How can I avoid that without set them in other properties/identifiers? If they are re-created everytime, it won't be good for JS performance.

Comment: I don't think it would be bad either, just thought it worth mentioning. But obviously JS engines expect to create variables and know how to optimise the more common patterns. Bottom line is I create the variables I need and don't worry too much unless performance is bad in practice.

Comment: @CoolMan I don't think creating 2 variables is the bottle-neck of your code. But if you want to avoid creating them in each call, you can declare them in an upper scope (but not the global one).

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm currently wondering if that such engine works equally in every browser. I believe it may work greatly in modern browsers, unless in the bit recent or old. I can detect which browser the user is using, though.

Comment: @Oriol It's possible the loop function spam in variable notation into memory. I do that, but I'm afraid of doing that again in a text I generate in my compiler of Lua to JS because it can respectively give problems in use of program variables - there I'm currently notating all variables into array items.

Comment: @CoolMan,well that should really increase the memory-usage, and drop the overall performance. That's really the wrong point to optimize anything. The only way local variables may affect the performance in a bad way, is when you have to many (like 50+) diferent variables in one function so that the JIT-compiler doesn't even try to optimize this function anymore. But to this point, EVERYTHING ELSE in your code should be considered more than this "problem".

Answer (score -1):

Variables of `number` type take up very little memory, relatively speaking. What you should really worry about is repeatedly initiating bigger objects, like variables that require to be initiated with `var foo = new ObjType()`, for instance. Declaring simple counter variables in for loops is unnoticeable in today's computers.

If you're really worried about maximum optimization, you could do something like:

`var i, b;
function onFrame(){
    for(i = 0; i !== 10; i++){
        for(b = 0; b !== 10; b++){
        }
    }
}`

That way you only declare those variables once. Although the difference in performance will be negligible.

Comment: Small note: JS doesn't have integers, only 64 bit floating point numbers.

Comment: I do something of kind, but I want to do it different in my compiler of Lua to JS. To avoid problems I should create variables for each variable created in the user program.

Comment: @Marco Del Valle, in your example i and b are global vars; it's generally a bad practice to declare what should clearly be function-scoped globally, not just from memory management / performance considerations, but from the standpoint of ease of accidentally changing these values elsewhere in code - a recipe for headaches... Since in JS all vars are function-scoped anyway, it would be sufficient to declare them in the loop: `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { ... }`

Comment: Good point, @CoolBots. I agree that declaring the variables in the loop would be easiest, cleanest, and less prone to mistakes, but since Cool Man is really worried about declaring them only once, I gave him a solution that would only declare those vars once, and reuse them.

Comment: @CoolBots, it's true, but it still keeps the performance question of creating variables in memory everytime. These loop data can be hosted in some objects or arrays also, but I like this simple style with `i`.

Comment: @CoolBots - the code in this answer isn't necessarily global, it could be in some other containing function not shown - the main point of the example is to declare them outside `onFrame()`. @CoolMan - "hosting" the variables in objects or arrays has its own performance cost, having to do property lookups every time you use the variables.

Comment: @nnnnnn Arrays are faster than objects when indexing item value, I believe. Currently, I do full part of project scope in a anonymous function sometimes, at least in my Lua compiler... yet...

Comment: I see, that makes sense in light of the question then. I read it as a generalized example, my apologies.

Comment: @Oriol, basically it's true, but not entirely. JS knows only numbers, no ints, no doubles. But the underlying engines know them, and they utilize them. When you're doing bit-operations for example. Also when storing (signed) integers with values < 31!!! bits, the Array is optimized for this data-type (behind the scenes) That means lower memory-footprint and it's way faster. So actually JS uses 32-bit signed ints, although it doesn't know them. `>>>` actually even creates an 32bit uint.

Comment: @CoolMan, it depends on how you use an Array, wether it is really faster than an Object. If you mix different data-types in the Array, it might be stored the same way as an actual Object. In the worst case, even as an hash-table wich has a way bigger memory-footprint than a local var, and is multiple times slower.

Comment: And accessing variables from an enclosed scope has it's own lookup-cost, similar to the lookup-cost for an Object. And it doesn't make sence, since the function-call itself has a way bigger performance-impact than allocating these two tiny variables. The only thing you don't want to do is creating to many variables in a singe function (like >50 or so) because then the JIT-compiler may decide, that it doesn't even try to optimize this function.

Comment: I see no reason why the code recommended in this question is the right solution give the context shown.  You don't go putting variables into an unnecessarily higher scope.  That's just bad programming.

Comment: @jfriend00 Did you read the comments? It's what Cool Man was asking for. We discussed that it was poor practice, but he still wanted to go in this direction.

Comment: The OP shows no context in the question that suggests it's a good recommendation to declare the variables outside the containing function.  Your answer is simply not a good programming practice or a good recommendation for the situation described.  And, corrupting your programming structure to try to save on the allocation/garbage collection of an occasional variable is also wrong.

Comment: The only time you would ever consider trying to micro-optimize variable allocation is after you had a proven performance problem in a specific piece of code and you had measured and proven that the variable allocation was actually causing the problem.  In any other proven case, corrupting your code design is just foolish and is considered foolhardy pre-optimization.